# verify x-509 certificate signature and validity c code

Tags: c, certificate, verification

I am searching for small free open source X-509 certificate verification code written in C language for embedded device that do the following:

- read X509 certificate and parse it
- check if it signed by specific CA certificate
- check the validity period for the certificate

The code should be without any dependencies like OpenSSL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are some good sources to look at:

- [wolfSSL](https://github.com/wolfSSL/wolfssl/blob/dd2915f4faa6c5322ccdecefedd13fe8d524db2e/wolfcrypt/src/asn.c)
- [tropicssl](https://github.com/axic/tropicssl/blob/master/library/x509parse.c)

As far as I know, wolfSSL is pretty popular for embedded applications. You will probably find good support when porting it. I haven't taken a closer look at tropicssl but it looks good, too.

And of course, you can always try to port OpenSSL as well, you may begin from here:

- [OpenSSL](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/master/crypto/x509/x509_vfy.c)

Comment: Thanks a lot ... Now I have used xyssl